# Getting error while trying to install Pyro Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyro

I'm getting this error whenever I try to install PyRO:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>
> command: 'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lxpur7nd\pyro\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lxpur7nd\pyro\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-f9isu850'
>
> cwd: C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lxpur7nd\pyro\
>
> Complete output (6 lines):
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lxpur7nd\pyro\setup.py", line 23
> exec code in constants
> ^
> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

I'm installing it using `pip install` method.

Comment: Please include the way you try to install the package (ex pip, git etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python 3.9 has a lot of bugs, i tried to install opencv for python and couldn't do so. You can do either of this:

1. use the older version of python like python 3.8/7 or something
2. wait till python fixes the bugs, that will be by mid december

Comment: I think that @Nikhil Singh is using python 3.8 bc the error says `'c:\users\singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' `

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to install with Python 3.7. According to the PyPI page,

https://pypi.org/project/Pyro/

Pyro seems not to be maintained anymore. I could install Pyro4 or Pyro5 with, e.g.

```
pip install pyro4
```

with no problems.